# changing to dark in Themeresource for a simple windows app

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Recently I have started exploring VS2015 and I went through the basic tutorial of how to create a hello world using c++ in VS2015(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974580.aspx).

After copying and building the exact same thing, the background color that I got was light instead of dark like the example shown in the link. I know ThemeResource is responsible for the background color and there are light and dark color scheme.How do you use dark instead of default(light)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the App.xaml

```
<Application ...    RequestedTheme="Dark"
```

But take care that depending on the version of Windows Preview and the Phone it can be applied or not. In the 10074 it works in previous it does not.

*IMPROVEMENT* (when you want to change the theme in Runtime):

Suppose you want to change the theme on runtime, if you want to change the Application Current RequestedTheme you cannot but you can do the following:

```
MainPage.Current.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
```

Apart the Popups won't change the theme as well(Take care about your Window Layout)

```
Popup.RequestedTheme = ((Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as Page).RequestedTheme;
```

Comment: ahh Thanks a lot! I am not very familiar with all the files and need to figure out  how they work together.

Comment: would you mark as answer?, Thanks and ask what you need

Comment: when I compile I get a warning saying no SDK were found...also when I follow the guide and try to use the VisualStateManager to change the size of UI, it just doesnt work....

Comment: What version of Windows do you have?

Comment: I solved the problem already. It was because the tutorial does not have the x:Name attribute included. Thanks anyway